# RxJS won't execute pipe operators after executing either first or find with a false predicate

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have this observable subscribtion

```
this.tooltipEventSubject.pipe(
    filter(event => event.type === "show"),
    tap(() => this.tooltipContent.loading = true),
    filter(() => this.messageContent?.sender !== undefined && this.tooltipContent.success === undefined),
    mergeMap(() => this.jabService.searchEntityInAddressBook(this.messageContent?.sender ?? "")),
    mergeMap(response => response.values),
    filter(response => response !== undefined) as OperatorFunction<Entity | undefined, Entity>,
    tap(() => console.log("before first")),
    find(entity => entity.name === this.messageContent?.sender),
    tap(() => console.log("after first")),
).subscribe({
    next: () => console.log("next"),
    error: err => console.log(err),
    complete: () => console.log("complete")
})
```

It hits the "find" predicate (checked with debugger) and then does nothing.

I have tried a lot of operators, like first following by a catchError, here on this example I have find.

It is getting to "before first", but then it won't print anything else. I am aware that the find predicate is returning false, and it should. But why does it stop running ? Shouldn't it return "undefined" to the following operators ? And shouldn't it even print "complete" ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: This is a misunderstanding of what `find()` operator does. It does not behave like `Array.find()`. Check RxJS docs https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` operator will wait until predicate returns true and till then it will not emit any data even `undefined`.

`find` will emit `undefined` only when `source observable` **completes** and none of the data match.

In your case source observable is a form event,So it will not be completed unless you do.`Ex.takeUntil ..`

I am providing two example.

**`Ex. 1`**

```ts
from([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(
  tap((data) => console.log('Before find', data)),
  find((data) => data > 5),
  tap((data) => console.log('After find', data))
)
.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
  error: console.error,
  complete: () => console.log('Completed'),
});
```

**Output:**

```
Before find 1

Before find 2

Before find 3

Before find 4

After find undefined

undefined

Completed
```

**`Ex. 2`**

```
<button id="btnFind">Find</button>
```

```ts
const btnFind = document.getElementById('btnFind');
let count: number = 0;
fromEvent(btnFind, 'click')
  .pipe(
    tap(() => count++),
    // takeUntil(timer(5000)),
    tap((count) => console.log('Before find', count)),
    find(() => count > 4),
    tap((count) => console.log('After find', count))
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (e) => console.log(e),
    error: console.error,
    complete: () => console.log('Completed'),
  });
```

In 2nd example It will emit after 5th click or if you uncomment `takeUntil` then after 5 seconds

Comment: oh god thank you ! Might find another way then

Answer (score 0):

If your predicate returns false that means there's no value that matches your condition and the 'find' operator simply will not return any value in this case.

check official rxjs doc for more: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/find

Comment: That's unfortunate, because 'find' is something I tried *after* trying first, which did not throw any error at all.
Replacing the find by "first" doesn't call the "error" subscribtion callback

Comment: `first` / `find` to emit error / undefined also `Observable` needs to be completed.

Comment: Oh god it's because it's not completed omg
thank you !